# Display a chosen users tweets using twitter api in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am trying to display a chosen users tweets in my rails app. Right now the way I have it, it is pulling up their tweets and any time they are mentioned. I just want the tweets that they post and nothing else. I will not have their log in info. This will just work for public accounts. This is the code I have so far.

```
client.search(user_id=@band.twitter).take(20).collect do |tweet|
```

the @band.twitter is where I am storing the bands twitter handle. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the example at https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/README.md not helpful? Specifically "Collect the three most recent marriage proposals to @justinbieber"

Comment: That did not work for me but this thing I just tried worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to have Worked for me.

```
client.user_timeline(@band.twitter).take(20).collect do
```